# JPAプロジェクトにおいてRepositoryファイル作成時にビルドエラーが起きる

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

## エラー内容

Eclipse上で作成したJPAプロジェクトにおいて、Repositoryファイルを作成して以下のように記述したところ、次のようなエラー（赤い波線）が発生しました。

#### Reposirotyファイル記述内容

```
package model;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

@Repository
public interface ActivityRepository extends JpaRepository<Activity, Long> {}
```

#### package modelの部分で起こっているエラー

```
型 org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor を解決できません。必要な .class ファイルから間接的に参照されています
```

#### JpaRepositoryの部分で起こっているエラー

```
ビルド・パスが不完全であるため、プロジェクトはビルドされませんでした。org.springframework.data.domain.Example のクラス・ファイルが見つかりません。ビルド・パスを修正してから、このプロジェクトをビルドしてください
```

## 環境・プロジェクトの状況など

#### プロジェクトのビルドパス

[image: ビルドパス]

#### ビルドパスに関して補足

domainフォルダ以下は確かに存在していないです。（Mavenファイルにどう記述すれば取ってこれるかもよくわかりません）
[image: domainフォルダ以下は確かに存在しない]

#### やってみたことなど

ネット上で、JPAプロジェクトおよびReposirotyファイルを作成している人のブログを探し、同じように書いてみたのですが、うまくいきません。 
org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor　も　org.springframework.data.domain.Example　も、Mavenファイルにどのように記述すれば取り込んでこれるかもよくわかっておりません。  
恐縮ですが、何かアドバイスいただけないでしょうか。

Comment: もともとやりたかったことは、SpringBootのプロジェクトからDB操作を行いたい、ということでした。
SpringBootのことをあまりわからないままJPAプロジェクトを新規作成してRepositoryファイル等を作成しており上述のようなエラーが発生していました。しかし、もともとのSpringBootのプロジェクト内でRepositoryファイル等を作成したら問題は発生しなくなりました。
SpringBoot やJPAなどについての理解が甘いまま雰囲気で作ろうとしていたのが根本原因でした・・・。

Comment: Dash さん> もし今回の問題が解決した場合は、解決方法を回答として投稿し、質問を解決済みにしていただけませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

もともとDB操作をやりたかったSpringBootのプロジェクトはまた別にJPAプロジェクトを新規作成し、Repositoryファイルを作成していたため、上記のエラーが出ておりました。
本などを参考にして、もともとのSpringBootプロジェクト内にReposirotyファイルを作成して同様に記述したところ、エラーは発生しなくなりました。

supaさん、解決時の対処についてご指摘ありがとうございます。自分のコメントだと４８時間後でないと解決済みマークができないようなので、後日解決済みにします。